# How to determine the size of a System.Type value?

Tags: f#

How to determine the size of a Type value?

```
let typ = if true then (123).GetType() else "asdf".GetType();;
let sz = sizeof<typ>

  let sz = sizeof<typ>;;
  ----------------^^^
error FS0039
```

One solution is to use Marshal.SizeOf(obj), but may be another solution exists?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to know the size?

Answer (score 5):

I think `Marshal.SizeOf` is what you are looking for here. Note that there are two overloads of the method.

- `Marshal.SizeOf(t)` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) takes `System.Type` as an argument and returns the size of the type that is represented by the `System.Type` value (I believe this is what you want.)
- `Marshal.SizeOf(structure)` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) takes any `object` and returns the size of the structure based on the runtime type.

The `sizeof<'T>` construct in F# works only when the type is statically know, but then it generates nice single `sizeof` IL instruction (as you can see [from the source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/1745b5f7b19bdb285f3a9c06527b22baf01d41f9/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L471)).

Answer (score 0):

This will get the size of a type variable:

```
sizeof<System.Type>
```

The hint is that anything inside `< ... >` needs to be a type, not a variable.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking for - this just returns the size of the `System.Type` reference type (not the value type it represents).